# Firebase Retrieve Image as Url pass tableView as Image (Swift)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve my data as URL and pass my another viewController.

Here is my retrieve data's code:

```
private func loadPlaces() {


        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("places").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            let images = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            // self.places.removeAll()
            for (_, value) in images {
                let userToShow = historicalPlaces()
                if let img = value["imagePath"] as? String,
                    let name = value["name"] as? String,
                    let information = value["information"] as? String
                {


                    userToShow.historyImage = img
                    userToShow.historyName = name
                    userToShow.information = information
                    self.places.append(userToShow)

                }


            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        //  ref.removeAllObservers()

    }
```

In this code I'm using extension which can read URL.

Extension code here.

```
extension UIImageView {
 func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

}
```

and here I print my images and labels to viewController.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellIdentifier = "historyTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HistoryTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of historyTableViewCell.")
        }


        let place = places[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = place.historyName
        cell.photoImageView.downloadImage(from: place.historyImage!)


        return cell
    }
```

and this is the cell control code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

        case "ShowDetail":
            guard let historyDetail = segue.destination as? selectedPlaceViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }

            guard let selectedPlace = sender as? HistoryTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
            }

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedPlace) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }

            let Place = places[indexPath.row]

            historyDetail.selectedPlaces = Place

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
        }
    }
```

now whenever I click the cell which has view and label print it's images and labels to another viewController.

I try something like this:

```
import UIKit

class selectedPlaceViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    var selectedPlaces: historicalPlaces?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        nameTextField.delegate = self
        if let history = selectedPlaces {
            navigationItem.title = history.historyName
            nameTextField.text = history.historyName
         //   photoImageView.downloadImage(from: selectedPlaces [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)].historyImage!)


        }
    }   
}
```

In this code I can retrieve labels from another viewController but I can't retrieve images. How can I retrieve Images from another viewCell URL to image.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Are you trying to copy images and labels from one view controller to another? If so, why? If not, can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's similar to this(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/) app but with firebase-database i can retrieve images and labels from database into cells but when I click the cell i want to display cell's image and label to another viewController like in this app. I can pass label  but I retrieve image with Url so i cant pass image to another viewController. When I try pass cell's image the xcode says it's string. so i must pass the url value from another viewController and display it.